# How can I change print quality and print profile settings when using Airprint?

Tags: iphone, ipad, network, ios, printing

I just got a new wireless printer and I love that it lets me print from any device on my wireless network, even my iPhone. There is, however, one feature that appears to be missing.

When I print from my computer, I can select different print quality settings: "Draft, Normal, Photo, Black & White". I don't seem to be able to do this from my iPhone when using Airprint. I can only click "print", choose my printer, and the item gets printed at whatever settings Apple deems best at that moment.

But what if I want to lower the print quality to save on ink? Or print a photo in black and white? Is there any way to change those settings?

Comment: What kind/model of printer are you using? Do you have other computers (Mac, PC) in your network which could act as a print server?

Comment: @patrix the printer is an HP Officejet Pro 8610. Yes, I have a Windows desktop that could feasibly be configured as a print server. Would that allow me to set advanced print quality settings on my mobile devices?

Comment: Would https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/hp-eprint/id299531647?mt=8 help? I don't have a HP printer so I can't test it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Apple, [AirPrint on iPhone](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201387) is simplified application.

It only lets you choose the printer and the number of copies, but not print quality etc.. in other words it use the current Printer defaults.

So what can you do?

Log in to the printer's set up page IP address that you need to know it first, but it is something like (192.168. xxx) and change it there.  However, this solution will affect all following documents until you change it again.

Answer (score 0):

With iOS 9 AirPrint now has the option to print Black & White.

Screenshot:

[image: Black & White AirPrint]

Answer (score 0):

Standard Apple answer - "there's an app for that"
I have, no, had the same issue with a Canon printer. In the app store I did a search for 'Airprint' and found a long list of apps from several major manufactures.  Downloaded the Canon app and I can now control all the settings when I airprint to my printer.